# Manually created Figure/Table labels in Word not showing up in List of Figures and List of Tables

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I am having difficulty getting all my captions to show in Figure and Table lists in Word 2013. I have a 400+ page document with multiple Appendices. The Appendices titles are set up using a multilevel list (Home tab, Paragraph section, Multilevel List button) with Chapter Titles as level 1 and Appendix Titles as level 7.
I used the 'Insert Caption' prompts (References tab, Captions section, Insert Caption button) to create all my figure and table captions. I thought that by using a multilevel list I would be able to use 'Insert Caption' dialog box with 'Include chapter number' turned on within 'Numbering' and changing the 'Chapter starts with style' dropdown list changed to Heading 7. This did not work, and kept a 1.1 numbering style instead of A.1 for Appendix A... and so on.

So, instead, I went to 'New Label' within the 'Insert Caption' dialog box and created new labels for each Appendix's figures and tables (Figure A., Figure B., Table A., Table B.) which works great to get them to number correctly. However, these semi-manually created labels are not showing up in my List of Figures and List of Tables at the beginning of the document.

I have Appendices A through I, so adding these captions to the lists manually will be a real pain. Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Word doesn't allow multiple labels in one table of figures. You will need to add a continuous break after your first list and then add a new table of figures featuring the created label.

Comment: This is correct except there is no need to add a continuous break between the two tables - just insert the table for the new label after the table for the existing label. I then usually delete the extra return between the tables so it looks like one table in the finished product.

Answer (score 0):

you should simply insert the table of contents for Figure A label after your main table of contents followed by other appendix labels.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).